# Is there any way I can add a Scrollbar to a StickyGroupedListView in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to add a scrollbar to my StickyGroupedListView, but the scroll controllers of both items are different, the scrollbar needs a ScrollController and the StickyGroupedListView needs a GroupedItemScrollController

[image]

```
Scrollbar(
      interactive: true,
      controller: widget.scrollController,
      radius: const Radius.circular(10),
      thickness: 5,
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 25, right: 5, left: 5),
        child: StickyGroupedListView<Repostaje, DateTime>(
          elements: repostajes,
          groupBy: (Repostaje repostaje) => DateTime(
            repostaje.fecha!.year,
            repostaje.fecha!.month,
          ),
          groupSeparatorBuilder: (Repostaje repostaje) =>
              separadorRepostje(repostaje, themeProvider),
          stickyHeaderBackgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          itemBuilder: (context, repostaje) => repostajeCard(repostaje),
          itemComparator: (item1, item2) =>
              item1.fecha!.compareTo(item2.fecha!),
          itemScrollController: widget.scrollController,
          physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(
              parent: BouncingScrollPhysics()),
          order: StickyGroupedListOrder.DESC,
        ),
      ),
    ),
```

And the package https://pub.dev/packages/sticky_grouped_list

I have tried to cast the GroupedItemScrollController to a ScrollController but fails

Thanks in advance .

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution by searching from a lot of different websites and videos. The easiest way was to nest the different Columns with a StickyHeader (https://pub.dev/packages/sticky_headers) inside a ListView and then a simple Scrollbar with a scrollcontroller, here is the code I used:

```
Scrollbar(
        interactive: true,
        controller: widget.scrollController,
        radius: const Radius.circular(10),
        thickness: 5,
        child: ListView.builder(
          physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(parent: BouncingScrollPhysics()),
          controller: widget.scrollController,
          itemCount: repostajesGrouped.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            List<Widget> widgets = [];
            for (var repostaje in repostajesGrouped[index]) {
              widgets.add(
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5),
                  child: repostajeCard(repostaje, themeProvider),
                ),
              );
            }

            return StickyHeaderBuilder(
              builder: (context, stuckAmount) {
                return separadorRepostje(repostajesGrouped[index][0], themeProvider);
              },
              content: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: widgets,
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
```

The variable repostajesGrouped is just a list of lists and grouped by date:

```
List<List<Repostaje>> repostajesGrouped = groupBy(repostajesToShow, (Repostaje repostaje) {
  return DateTime(repostaje.fecha!.year, repostaje.fecha!.month);
}).values.toList();
```

To use groupby: `import 'package:collection/collection.dart';`

Comment: can u share full code or github link, so i can use properly...

Comment: Hi @RahulZx, what more do you need?

Comment: jumpto index for dynamic height element (child) of list

Comment: If I have understood your comment, you need the child element that is inside the `ListView.builder` to be able to set the height?
I have a `Card` widget with a `ListTile` child, and the result looks like [this](https://gyazo.com/f3d2217660f633c0268d0e5e37f3b073)

 If not, please specify what you need and I will tell you.

Comment: yes im looking for exaclty same with jumpto index facility